# How to remove spaces between bar in d3.js grouped bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have following d3.js code which helps to create grouped bar chart. My data consist of different states and its population by age categories. In this data few age categories(14 to 17 Years, 18 to 24 Years, 25 to 44 Years) are missing in 'TX' and 'NY' states. So when we create grouped bar chart using this data, its creating empty space in between the bars for missing data. How can we get rid off this empty space for missing data in between the bars in d3.js.
I found a same question in [github](https://github.com/d3/d3/issues/3426), but nobody given solution for that.

@mbostock @jasondavies @gordonwoodhull @esjewett @vogievetsky @jheer @connorgr @Fil @petulla @tmcw
@shikhaagrawal23 @gkumar100

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>

.axis .domain {
 display: none;
}

</style>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
   margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
   width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
   height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
   g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var x0 = d3.scaleBand()
   .rangeRound([0, width])
   .paddingInner(0.1);

var x1 = d3.scaleBand()
   .padding(0.05);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
   .rangeRound([height, 0]);

var z = d3.scaleOrdinal()
   .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);
   
   
var data = [
 {
   "State": "CA",
   "Under 5 Years": 2704659,
   "5 to 13 Years": 4499890,
   "14 to 17 Years": 2159981,
   "18 to 24 Years": 3853788,
   "25 to 44 Years": 10604510,
   "45 to 64 Years": 8819342,
   "65 Years and Over": 4114496
 },
 {
   "State": "TX",
   "Under 5 Years": 2027307,
   "5 to 13 Years": 3277946,   
   "45 to 64 Years": 5656528,
   "65 Years and Over": 2472223
 },
 {
   "State": "NY",
   "Under 5 Years": 1208495,
   "5 to 13 Years": 2141490,    
   "25 to 44 Years": 5355235,
   "45 to 64 Years": 5120254,
   "65 Years and Over": 2607672
 },
 {
   "State": "FL",
   "Under 5 Years": 1140516,
   "5 to 13 Years": 1938695,
   "14 to 17 Years": 925060,
   "18 to 24 Years": 1607297,
   "25 to 44 Years": 4782119,
   "45 to 64 Years": 4746856,
   "65 Years and Over": 3187797
 },
 {
   "State": "IL",
   "Under 5 Years": 894368,
   "5 to 13 Years": 1558919,
   "14 to 17 Years": 725973,
   "18 to 24 Years": 1311479,
   "25 to 44 Years": 3596343,
   "45 to 64 Years": 3239173,
   "65 Years and Over": 1575308
 },
 {
   "State": "PA",
   "Under 5 Years": 737462,
   "5 to 13 Years": 1345341,
   "14 to 17 Years": 679201,
   "18 to 24 Years": 1203944,
   "25 to 44 Years": 3157759,
   "45 to 64 Years": 3414001,
   "65 Years and Over": 1910571
 }
];

 var keys  = Object.keys(data[0]);
  keys = keys.slice(1);

 x0.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.State; }));
 x1.domain(keys).rangeRound([0, x0.bandwidth()]);
 y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d3.max(keys, function(key) { return d[key]; }); })]).nice();

 g.append("g")
   .selectAll("g")
   .data(data)
   .enter().append("g")
     .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.State) + ",0)"; })
   .selectAll("rect")
   .data(function(d) { return keys.map(function(key) { return {key: key, value: d[key]}; }); })
   .enter().append("rect")
     .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.key); })
     .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
     .attr("width", x1.bandwidth())
     .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
     .attr("fill", function(d) { return z(d.key); });

 g.append("g")
     .attr("class", "axis")
     .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
     .call(d3.axisBottom(x0));

 g.append("g")
     .attr("class", "axis")
     .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(null, "s"))
   .append("text")
     .attr("x", 2)
     .attr("y", y(y.ticks().pop()) + 0.5)
     .attr("dy", "0.32em")
     .attr("fill", "#000")
     .attr("font-weight", "bold")
     .attr("text-anchor", "start")
     .text("Population");

 var legend = g.append("g")
     .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
     .attr("font-size", 10)
     .attr("text-anchor", "end")
   .selectAll("g")
   .data(keys.slice().reverse())
   .enter().append("g")
     .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

 legend.append("rect")
     .attr("x", width - 19)
     .attr("width", 19)
     .attr("height", 19)
     .attr("fill", z);

 legend.append("text")
     .attr("x", width - 24)
     .attr("y", 9.5)
     .attr("dy", "0.32em")
     .text(function(d) { return d; });
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: When you remove the missing data, how should the resulting graph look?  Should the remaining bars move to the left or center leaving the groups the same size?  Or should the remaining bars get wider leaving the groups the same size? Or should the group size vary based on how many remaining bars?    Each of these is possible but I didn't want to waste a lot of time coding a solution without specifics.

Comment: @Mark I need a chart like [this](https://img.hotimg.com/bar-image-Question.png).

 Should the group size vary based on how many remaining bars? 
 Yes, All the bars should have same width, space between the bar's and x axis labels(CA,TX,NY etc) should be removed.

Answer (score 2):

I have put in a lot of hard work to solve the problem and tried to make your code dynamic to accommodate various cases. Kindly check it out.

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
   margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
   width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
   height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
   g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var x0 = d3.scaleBand()
   .rangeRound([0, width])
   .paddingInner(0.1);

var x1 = d3.scaleBand()
   .padding(0.05);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
   .rangeRound([height, 0]);

var z = d3.scaleOrdinal()
   .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);
   
   
var data = [
 {
   "State": "CA",
   "Under 5 Years": 2704659,
   "5 to 13 Years": 4499890,
   "14 to 17 Years": 2159981,
   "18 to 24 Years": 3853788,
   "25 to 44 Years": 10604510,
   "45 to 64 Years": 8819342,
   "65 Years and Over": 4114496
 },
 {
   "State": "TX",
   "Under 5 Years": 2027307,
   "5 to 13 Years": 3277946,   
   "45 to 64 Years": 5656528,
   "65 Years and Over": 2472223
 },
 {
   "State": "NY",
   "Under 5 Years": 1208495,
   "5 to 13 Years": 2141490,    
   "25 to 44 Years": 5355235,
   "45 to 64 Years": 5120254,
   "65 Years and Over": 2607672
 },
 {
   "State": "FL",
   "Under 5 Years": 1140516,
   "5 to 13 Years": 1938695,
   "14 to 17 Years": 925060,
   "18 to 24 Years": 1607297,
   "25 to 44 Years": 4782119,
   "45 to 64 Years": 4746856,
   "65 Years and Over": 3187797
 },
 {
   "State": "IL",
   "Under 5 Years": 894368,
   "5 to 13 Years": 1558919,
   "14 to 17 Years": 725973,
   "18 to 24 Years": 1311479,
   "25 to 44 Years": 3596343,
   "45 to 64 Years": 3239173,
   "65 Years and Over": 1575308
 },
 {
   "State": "PA",
   "Under 5 Years": 737462,
   "5 to 13 Years": 1345341,
   "14 to 17 Years": 679201,
   "18 to 24 Years": 1203944,
   "25 to 44 Years": 3157759,
   "45 to 64 Years": 3414001,
   "65 Years and Over": 1910571
 }
];


  var legthList = data.map((d,i) => {
   return Object.keys(d).length
  });
  var maxLegth = (Math.max(...legthList)-1)
  
  var findMaxObjPro = data.filter((el => Object.keys(el).length === maxLegth+1))
  
  var keys  = Object.keys(findMaxObjPro[0]);
  keys = keys.slice(1);
  
 x0.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.State; }));
 x1.domain(keys).rangeRound([0, x0.bandwidth()]);
 y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d3.max(keys, function(key) { return d[key]; }); })]).nice();

 g.append("g")
   .selectAll("g")
   .data(data)
   .enter().append("g")
     .attr("transform", function(d) { 
     let {State,...rest} = d
     let localKeys = Object.keys(rest)
     let bandwidth = (x1.bandwidth()*(maxLegth-localKeys.length))/2;
     return "translate(" + (x0(d.State)+bandwidth) + ",0)"; 
     })
   .selectAll("rect")
   .data(function(d) { 
    // remove State field
    let {State,...rest} = d
    let localKeys = Object.keys(rest)
    return localKeys.map(function(key) { return {key: key, value: d[key]}; }); })
   .enter().append("rect")
     .attr("x", function(d,i) {
      return (x1(keys[0]) + i*(x1.bandwidth())) 
     })
     .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
     .attr("width", x1.bandwidth())
     .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
     .attr("fill", function(d) { return z(d.key); });

 g.append("g")
     .attr("class", "axis")
     .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
     .call(d3.axisBottom(x0));

 g.append("g")
     .attr("class", "axis")
     .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(null, "s"))
   .append("text")
     .attr("x", 2)
     .attr("y", y(y.ticks().pop()) + 0.5)
     .attr("dy", "0.32em")
     .attr("fill", "#000")
     .attr("font-weight", "bold")
     .attr("text-anchor", "start")
     .text("Population");

 var legend = g.append("g")
     .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
     .attr("font-size", 10)
     .attr("text-anchor", "end")
   .selectAll("g")
   .data(keys.slice().reverse())
   .enter().append("g")
     .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

 legend.append("rect")
     .attr("x", width - 19)
     .attr("width", 19)
     .attr("height", 19)
     .attr("fill", z);

 legend.append("text")
     .attr("x", width - 24)
     .attr("y", 9.5)
     .attr("dy", "0.32em")
     .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

```css
.axis .domain {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This helps me a lot. Thanks @akash-ram for your time and effort.

Comment: Is it possible @akash-ram, bars with same width and  space between the bar's and x axis labels(CA,TX,NY etc) can be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Your request is surprisingly difficult.  The issue is that in your example code the outer group scale is using a scale band.  By definition, this will always create **equal size groups**.  To create un-equal size groups, the only way I can think to do it is by hand calculating them.  There's my quick implementation with hopefully helpful comments.

```html
<html>
  <style>
    .axis .domain {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
  <svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var svg = d3.select('svg'),
      margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40 },
      width = +svg.attr('width') - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = +svg.attr('height') - margin.top - margin.bottom,
      g = svg
        .append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

    var data = [
      {
        State: 'CA',
        'Under 5 Years': 2704659,
        '5 to 13 Years': 4499890,
        '14 to 17 Years': 2159981,
        '18 to 24 Years': 3853788,
        '25 to 44 Years': 10604510,
        '45 to 64 Years': 8819342,
        '65 Years and Over': 4114496,
      },
      {
        State: 'TX',
        'Under 5 Years': 2027307,
        '5 to 13 Years': 3277946,
        '45 to 64 Years': 5656528,
        '65 Years and Over': 2472223,
      },
      {
        State: 'NY',
        'Under 5 Years': 1208495,
        '5 to 13 Years': 2141490,
        '25 to 44 Years': 5355235,
        '45 to 64 Years': 5120254,
        '65 Years and Over': 2607672,
      },
      {
        State: 'FL',
        'Under 5 Years': 1140516,
        '5 to 13 Years': 1938695,
        '14 to 17 Years': 925060,
        '18 to 24 Years': 1607297,
        '25 to 44 Years': 4782119,
        '45 to 64 Years': 4746856,
        '65 Years and Over': 3187797,
      },
      {
        State: 'IL',
        'Under 5 Years': 894368,
        '5 to 13 Years': 1558919,
        '14 to 17 Years': 725973,
        '18 to 24 Years': 1311479,
        '25 to 44 Years': 3596343,
        '45 to 64 Years': 3239173,
        '65 Years and Over': 1575308,
      },
      {
        State: 'PA',
        'Under 5 Years': 737462,
        '5 to 13 Years': 1345341,
        '14 to 17 Years': 679201,
        '18 to 24 Years': 1203944,
        '25 to 44 Years': 3157759,
        '45 to 64 Years': 3414001,
        '65 Years and Over': 1910571,
      },
    ];

    // stash the "keys" as part of the data
    // we will use them time and time again
    data.map((d) => {
      let keys = Object.keys(d);
      d.keys = keys.slice(1);
    });

    // calculate the yMax for all data
    const yMaxOfAllGroups = d3.max(data, function (d) {
      return d3.max(d.keys, function (key) {
        return d[key];
      });
    });

    // calculate the total number of bars in the graph
    const totalNumberOfBars = data.reduce((t, d) => {
      return t + d.keys.length;
    }, 0);

    // calculate a single bars width
    // here I've added 5 bars to represent the space between groups
    const barWidth = width / (totalNumberOfBars + data.length - 1);

    // calculate two things
    // 1 - outer range which essentially is a running total of where each group is located on x-axis
    // 2 - an array of varible width inner scales
    const outerRange = [];
    const innerScales = data.map((d, i) => {
      const w = d.keys.length * barWidth;
      if (i === 0) outerRange.push(w + barWidth)
      else outerRange.push(w + outerRange[i - 1] + barWidth);
      const s = d3.scaleBand().padding(0.05).domain(d.keys).rangeRound([0, w]);
      return s;
    });

    // fix outer range by appending a 0 and removing the last un-needed total
    outerRange.splice(0, 0, 0);
    outerRange.splice(-1);

    const outerScale = d3
      .scaleOrdinal()
      .range(outerRange)
      .domain(data.map((d) => d.State));

    var y = d3
      .scaleLinear()
      .rangeRound([height, 0])
      .domain([0, yMaxOfAllGroups])
      .nice();

    var z = d3
      .scaleOrdinal()
      .range([
        '#98abc5',
        '#8a89a6',
        '#7b6888',
        '#6b486b',
        '#a05d56',
        '#d0743c',
        '#ff8c00',
      ]);

    g.append('g')
      .selectAll('g')
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', d => 'translate(' + outerScale(d.State) + ',0)')
      .selectAll('rect')
      .data((d, i) => {
        // pass along the appropriate inner scale
        const s = innerScales[i];
        return d.keys.map(function (key) {
          return { scale: s, key: key, value: d[key] };
        });
      })
      .enter()
      .append('rect')
      .attr('x', d => d.scale(d.key))
      .attr('y', d => y(d.value))
      .attr('width', barWidth)
      .attr('height', d => height - y(d.value))
      .attr('fill', d => z(d.key));

    // added extra step to center ticks on group
    g.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'axis')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
      .call(d3.axisBottom(outerScale))
      .selectAll('.tick')
      .attr('transform', (d,i) => {
        const pos = innerScales[i].range()[1]/2 + outerScale(d);
        return 'translate(' + pos + ',0)';
      });        

    g.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'axis')
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(null, 's'))
      .append('text')
      .attr('x', 2)
      .attr('y', y(y.ticks().pop()) + 0.5)
      .attr('dy', '0.32em')
      .attr('fill', '#000')
      .attr('font-weight', 'bold')
      .attr('text-anchor', 'start')
      .text('Population');
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: This works for me. Thanks @mark for your valuable time and effort.